# External displays don't work with macOS, while with Boot Camp does

Tags: macos, mac, display, bootcamp

I have Mac Mini, PC, two external displays and [HDMI Matrix](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MYRX22F).

The problem is that without matrix displays work perfectly with Mac, but if I use matrix to connect them, displays show picture as normal, but after a few seconds they turn black. However if I use Windows Boot Camp on Mac, displays work perfectly without any problem.

Overall

- Displays **don't** work with macOS on Mac Mini and MacBook Pro using HDMI Matrix (only works for the first few seconds)
- Displays **do** work when connected directly to Mac (without Matrix)
- Displays **do** work with PC
- Displays **do** work with any other OS on Mac Mini or MacBook Pro (Boot Camp Windows/Linux)

Thus it looks like the problem is in macOS, but I don't know how to fix it.

Also, I already tried to reset NRAM, but it didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is this "matrix" you mention an HDMI switch of some sort? If so include the make and model number at the very least.

Comment: This is very “heavy” in leaning toward being a Customer Support question.  That said, how are you connecting your Mac to HDMI.  What adapter are you using?

Comment: @Allan First of all thanks for reply. I just don’t know where else I can find information about this problem. I went through many pages and sources to no avail. To connect Mac Mini I’m using built-in HDMI port. In case of MacBook — official Apple USB C - HDMI adapter.

Comment: The problem is drivers...Windows drivers are actually much better at handling the inconsistencies with clock sync signals in HDMI connections.  Usually the fix is to use an Active adapter, but in your case, you have a switch between the source and display and only the mfg knows how they handle things.  It might be that they are simply incompatible with Mac.

Comment: As a side note, one of the most difficult things I’ve had to deal with on Macs is they way displays are handled.  I had to abandon a digital signage project because Apple had “their way” of implementing graphics drivers.  I ended up putting Dell computers running BSD because I simply couldn’t make things work; Apple Support basically told me “Sony needs to conform to us, because our (Apple) way was better”.  Maybe, but Dell got the order for ~200 units.

Comment: I was doing some unrelated research, and ran across this and thought it might solve your issue - https://www.gefen.com/product/dvi-detective-n-EXT-DVI-EDIDN - It's less than $30 on [Amazon](https://amzn.to/39klQ9I).  I'd order one and test, but I don't have a matrix setup to replicate your conditions.